# Page loads forever when using clusters with Nodejs / Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cluster-computing

This is my application : app.js

```
/** Express **/
var express = require('express');
/** Create express application **/
var app = express();
/** Set application port **/
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

/** Set application view engine**/
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({
        defaultLayout: 'main',
        helpers: {
            section: function(name, options){
                if(!this._sections) this._sections = {};
                this._sections[name] = options.fn(this);
                return null;
            },
            parrot: function(options){
                return options.fn(this) + ' <b> parrot </b>';
            }
        }   
    });


/*** Cluster Logger**/
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    var cluster = require('cluster');
    if(cluster.isWorker) console.log('CLUSTER: Worker %d received request.', cluster.worker.id);
    next();
});

/** home page**/
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Welcome !!');
});

/** about page**/
app.get('/about', function(req, res){
    res.send('About us!');
});

/** contact page **/
app.get('/contact', function(req, res){
    res.send('contact us here');
});

// startServer in export/direct mode
function startServer(){
    app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
        console.log('Parrot started in '+app.get('env')+' mode on http://localhost:'+
            app.get('port')+
            '; \n press Ctrl-C to terminate');
    });
}
if(require.main === module){
    startServer();
}else{
    module.exports = startServer;
}
```

And this is parrot.js (with cluster include)

```
//import cluster
var cluster = require('cluster');

//startWorker
function startWorker(){
    var worker = cluster.fork();
    console.log('CLUSTER: Worker %d started', worker.id);
}

if(cluster.isMaster){

    //in case the cluster is Master
    require('os').cpus().forEach(function(){
        startWorker();
    });

    cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker){
        console.log('CLUSTER: Worker %d disconnected from the cluster', worker.id);
    });

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal){
        console.log('CLUSTER: Worker %d died with exit code %d (%s)', worker.id, code, signal);
        startWorker();
    });

}else{
    //in case cluster.isWorker (not master), run app directly
    require('./app.js')();
}
```

The problem, is that when I run `node app.js`, the app works just fine on `http://localhost:3000` ... and the page works great in the browser.

When I run as a set of clusters (with `node parrot.js`), everything looks good in console:

```
CLUSTER: Worker 1 started
CLUSTER: Worker 2 started
Parrot started in development mode on http://localhost:3000;
 press Ctrl-C to terminate
Parrot started in development mode on http://localhost:3000;
 press Ctrl-C to terminate
```

But, the page loads forever and nothing shows on the browser? I don't know what's the problem here. Sorry for my language for I'm a Node.js newbie.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what's the problem, but when I tested on another computer (with a 32-bit OS), the example above worked without any problems.

This is my result now, when I visit a page in the browser :

CLUSTER: Worker 1 started

```
CLUSTER: Worker 2 started
Parrot started in development mode on http://localhost:3333;
 press Ctrl-C to terminate
Parrot started in development mode on http://localhost:3333;
 press Ctrl-C to terminate
CLUSTER: Worker 2 received request.
CLUSTER: Worker 2 received request.
```

Just in case clusters didn't work for you, test on a different machine.

**Another question I have** : I don't know why all requests are served by cluster worker 2 (the last one started), it seems like worker 1 doesn't receive any requests.

Thanks